# I can't connect to my SQL database.

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is the code I've been using. And when I open it always says "Cannot connect to the server"

Please help me

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD','');
define('DATABASE','trialdb');

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
mysqli_select_db($link,DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE)) {
    die("Cannot connect to the server!");
} else {
    echo "Success! You are connected to the server!<br />";
}
if (mysqli_select_db($link,DATABASE)) {
    echo "Success! You are now connected to the database.";
} else {
    die ("Cannot connect to the database!");
}
?>
```

Comment: note: you don't need to invoke the connection twice, just check for `$link` in the `if` block, just check for the [connection error](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitmOnIz_vNAhUCF5QKHaauAl8QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fmysqli.connect-error.php&usg=AFQjCNGTaGUBimHBz5iC7HdOy0E2-pcZ5g&sig2=E8BenYEYYBnHM0tQlet4Mg&bvm=bv.127178174,d.dGo)

Comment: Long time not seen anyone using MySQLi procedural way. 
If you can't connect check your credentials and database name. Instead writing custom error mesages to the screen use "try catch" and throw an exception. or simply use mysqli_connect_errno() for more descriptive information like this: 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

Comment: Is your MySQL running? Can you connect with `mysql` command line? Is username/password combination correct? What if you swap `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`? So many questions ...

Comment: zxcvb if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). It takes time to research, test and write up these answers. Not very cool to ask & run.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of mysqli_connect is truthy so you've programmed your if statement to say: "Cannot connect to the server" in the case where you have connected to the server.

You might want to spend another 30 hours on a refresher on CS 101 topics starting with variables, if statements, and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code design has logical flaws.  You're connecting to the database twice, instead of connecting once and then checking for success.  In addition, the line

```
if (mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE))...show error
```

Will show an error when the connection is *successful*.  Use the design pattern below instead to get more helpful results.

```
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
if (!$link) {
    echo "MySQL error #". mysqli_connect_errno() .":<br/>";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
... //here it's safe to choose a DB and execute queries
```

This is for development. In production, don't show server errors in the browser.

Comment: and error reporting too, http://i.imgur.com/QlJYc2e.jpg

Comment: I actually had, then removed `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_error','1')` because I thought it superfluous to solving the OP's problem, but the OP would prob benefit from knowing about it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean to be snarkie, but this situation needs all the sonar on til he is comfortable.